# matlab symbolic array sorting problem with equationsToMatrix function

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, algebra

i am trying to obtain temperature distribution of a 2d plate. firs i create a symbolic T matrix in order:

```
T = sym('T',[n,n],'positive');
```

then using 2 formula (finite difference method):
for heated side

```
eqn(s,1) = (2*T(i+1,j))-P+(T(i,j+1))+(T(i,j-1))-(4*T(i,j))
```

and for interior points

```
eqn(s,1) = (T(i,j-1)+T(i,j+1)+T(i-1,j)+T(i+1,j)-(4*T(i,j)))
```

i store those symbolic equations in a column matrix. then using 'equationsToMatrix' function, i obtain A and b matrices of the system and then solve it using the gauss elimination. the problem is the symbolic T matrix. its elements are like this:

```
   T =
 
[ T1_1, T1_2, T1_3]
[ T2_1, T2_2, T2_3]
[ T3_1, T3_2, T3_3]
```

it works fine up to 10x10 system. But above 10, let's say 11x11 system, there occurs dislocation in A matrix which is obtained from equationsToMatrix function. as i see, the reason is because T11_1 comes before T1_1 or something like that i couldn't figure. and then the function equationsToMatrix sorts A matrix by name and this sort is incorrect. i need help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/equationstomatrix.html

> You can change the arrangement of the coefficient matrix by specifying other variable order.
>
> `vars = [x, z, y];`
> `[A,b] = equationsToMatrix(eqns,vars)`

Maybe you can use this second parameter to specify the order of the variables when generating your matrix?